# Bot joins and plays music but after disconnecting and rejoining it says 'Bot not connected to voice'

Tags: python, discord.py

So basically after rythm and groovy shutting down I decided to make my own music bot. My bot works perfectly but every time I play a song in the first run and when I make it disconnect and connect back the bot is in the voice channel but when i do `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: Not connected to voice.`
And I wanted to know if any of y'all knew how to fix it, Thanks!

My bot code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import tasks
import nacl
import DiscordUtils
import random
import asyncio


sm = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "sm ", help_command=None, intents = discord.Intents().all())
music = DiscordUtils.Music()

@sm.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(sm))

async def ch_pr():
    await sm.wait_until_ready()

    statuses = ["Work In Progress", "Music Bot", "Beta Stage"]

    while not sm.is_closed():
        status = random.choice(statuses)
        await sm.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle,activity=discord.Game(name=status))
        await asyncio.sleep(10)

sm.loop.create_task(ch_pr())

@sm.command()
async def join(ctx):
    voicetrue = ctx.author.voice
    if voicetrue is None:
        embedVar=discord.Embed(color=0x70cfff)
        embedVar.set_author(name=ctx.message.author.name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
        embedVar.add_field(name=":no_entry_sign: | Error! You are not in a voice channel!", value="-----------------------------")
        return await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)

    await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()

@sm.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    voicetrue = ctx.author.voice
    mevoicetrue = ctx.guild.me.voice
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    if voicetrue is None:
        embedVar=discord.Embed(color=0x70cfff)
        embedVar.set_author(name=ctx.message.author.name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
        embedVar.add_field(name=":no_entry_sign: | Error! You are not in a voice channel!", value="-----------------------------")
        return await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
    if mevoicetrue is None:
        embedVar=discord.Embed(color=0x70cfff)
        embedVar.set_author(name=ctx.message.author.name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
        embedVar.add_field(name=":no_entry_sign: | Error! I am not connected to a voice channel!", value="-----------------------------")
        return await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
    
    if ctx.message.author.voice:
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        server = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
        await server.disconnect()

@sm.command()
async def play(ctx, *, url):
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    
    if not player:
        player = music.create_player(ctx, ffmpeg_error_betterfix=True)

    if not ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
        await player.queue(url, search=True)
        song = await player.play()
        embedVar=discord.Embed(color=0x70cfff)
        embedVar.set_author(name=ctx.message.author.name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
        embedVar.add_field(name=f":arrow_forward: | Playing {song.name}", value="-----------------------------")
        await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
    else:
        song = await player.queue(url, search=True)
        embedVar=discord.Embed(color=0x70cfff)
        embedVar.set_author(name=ctx.message.author.name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
        embedVar.add_field(name=f":white_check_mark: | {song.name} has been added to the queue!", value="----------------------------")
        await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)

@sm.command()
async def queue(ctx):
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    embedVar=discord.Embed(color=0x70cfff)
    embedVar.set_author(name=ctx.message.author.name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
    embedVar.add_field(name=f"{', '.join([song.name for song in player.current_queue()])}", value="----------------------------")
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)

@sm.command()
async def pause(ctx):
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    song = await player.pause()
    embedVar=discord.Embed(color=0x70cfff)
    embedVar.set_author(name=ctx.message.author.name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
    embedVar.add_field(name=f":pause_button: | {song.name} has been paused!", value="----------------------------")
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)

@sm.command()
async def resume(ctx):
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    song = await player.resume()
    embedVar=discord.Embed(color=0x70cfff)
    embedVar.set_author(name=ctx.message.author.name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
    embedVar.add_field(name=f":arrow_forward: | Resuming {song.name}!", value="----------------------------")
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)

@sm.command()
async def loop(ctx):
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    song = await player.toggle_song_loop()
    if song.is_looping:
        embedVar=discord.Embed(color=0x70cfff)
        embedVar.set_author(name=ctx.message.author.name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
        embedVar.add_field(name=f":repeat: | {song.name} is now looping!", value="----------------------------")
        await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
    else:
        embedVar=discord.Embed(color=0x70cfff)
        embedVar.set_author(name=ctx.message.author.name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
        embedVar.add_field(name=f":no_entry_sign: | Error! {song.name} is not looping!", value="----------------------------")
        await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)

@sm.command()
async def np(ctx):
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    embedVar=discord.Embed(color=0x70cfff)
    embedVar.set_author(name=ctx.message.author.name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
    embedVar.add_field(name=f":arrow_forward: | {player.now_playing().name} is currently playing!", value="----------------------------")
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)

@sm.command()
async def remove(ctx, index):
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    song = await player.remove_from_queue(int(index))
    embedVar=discord.Embed(color=0x70cfff)
    embedVar.set_author(name=ctx.message.author.name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
    embedVar.add_field(name=f":white_check_mark: | {song.name} has been removed from queue!", value="----------------------------")
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)

@sm.command()
async def skip(ctx):
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    song = await player.skip(force=True)
    if len(song) == 2:
        embedVar=discord.Embed(color=0x70cfff)
        embedVar.set_author(name=ctx.message.author.name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
        embedVar.add_field(name=f":white_check_mark: | {song[0].name} has been skipped to {song[1].name}!", value="----------------------------")
        await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
    else:
        embedVar=discord.Embed(color=0x70cfff)
        embedVar.set_author(name=ctx.message.author.name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
        embedVar.add_field(name=f":white_check_mark: | {song.name} has been skipped!", value="----------------------------")
        await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)

 #help command

@sm.command()
async def help(ctx):
    embedVar=discord.Embed(color=0x70cfff)
    embedVar.set_author(name="Command List", icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
    embedVar.add_field(name="**sm join**", value="Joins the voice channel (Required for playing music)", inline=True)
    embedVar.add_field(name="**sm play**", value="Searches for a song name or plays a youtube link", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="**sm pause**", value="Pauses a song", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="**sm resume**", value="Resumes a song", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="**sm skip**", value="Skips the current song", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="**sm queue**", value="Shows the songs in queue", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="**sm remove**", value="Removes a song from queue", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="**sm np**", value="Shows the now playing song", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="**sm loop**", value="Loops the current song", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="**sm pause**", value="Pauses a song", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="**sm leave**", value="Leaves the voice channel", inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)

sm.run('Token')
```

Error Code:

```
Ignoring exception in command play:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/container/senmusic.py", line 70, in play
    song = await player.play()
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/DiscordUtils/Music.py", line 197, in play
    self.voice.play(source, after=lambda error: self.after_func(self.ctx, self.ffmpeg_opts, self.music, self.after_func, self.on_play_func, self.loop))
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/voice_client.py", line 555, in play
    raise ClientException('Not connected to voice.')
discord.errors.ClientException: Not connected to voice.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: Not connected to voice.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ctx.message.guild.voice_client.disconnect()` does not destroy the `player` object created by `music.create_player(ctx, ffmpeg_error_betterfix=True)`.

This means that when you try to play something after the bot has disconnected and connected to a voice channel, it will attempt to use the old `player` object which is no longer valid, even if the bot connects to the same voice channel.

Checking the [source code](https://github.com/toxicrecker/DiscordUtils/blob/master/DiscordUtils/Music.py) for `DiscordUtils.Music`, there are two methods that you can use to destroy `player`, either [`player.disable()`](https://github.com/toxicrecker/DiscordUtils/blob/master/DiscordUtils/Music.py#L169) or [`player.delete()`](https://github.com/toxicrecker/DiscordUtils/blob/master/DiscordUtils/Music.py#L291).

```py
@sm.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    voicetrue = ctx.author.voice
    mevoicetrue = ctx.guild.me.voice
    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    if voicetrue is None:
        embedVar=discord.Embed(color=0x70cfff)
        embedVar.set_author(name=ctx.message.author.name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
        embedVar.add_field(name=":no_entry_sign: | Error! You are not in a voice channel!", value="-----------------------------")
        return await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
    if mevoicetrue is None:
        embedVar=discord.Embed(color=0x70cfff)
        embedVar.set_author(name=ctx.message.author.name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
        embedVar.add_field(name=":no_entry_sign: | Error! I am not connected to a voice channel!", value="-----------------------------")
        return await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
    
    if ctx.message.author.voice:
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        server = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
        await server.disconnect()

        player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
        player.disable()
```

Comment: This fixed my problem, Thanks for the help!